# Update list on keyup

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api, onkeyup

I'm having some problems with list update after fetching API.

After each new letter the list should update and show only results that begin with typed letter.

Please help :)

Here is my JS code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', getJson);


function getJson() {
    fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=indie&entity=song')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            let result = '';
            data.results.forEach(function (song) {
                result += `<li>${song.artistName} - ${song.trackName}</li>`;
            });
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

        })
        .catch(function (empty) {
            console.log(empty);
        });
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Search songs</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Enter artist name or song:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input">

    <div class="loader"></div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case, but you should know that javascript is not rendering something only because you changed it. There is AnimationFrames and maybe you should use `requestAnimationFrame()` to update your html. More about `requestAnimationFrame()` and the event loop - https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this.
this is your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Search songs</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Enter artist name or song:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="term" placeholder="term">
    <input type="text" id="entity" placeholder="entity">

    <div class="loader"></div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and javascript:

```
var term = document.getElementById('term');
var entity = document.getElementById('entity');


document.addEventListener('keyup', getJson);


function getJson() {
    fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term='+term.value+'&entity='+entity.value)
        .then(function (response) {
            
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            
            let result = '';
            try{
                data.results.forEach(function (song) {
                    console.log(song);
                    result += `<li>${song.artistName} - ${song.trackName}</li>`;
                });
            }
            catch{}
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

        })
        .catch(function (empty) {
            console.log(empty);
        });
}
```

or if you want keyup event for certain elements:

```
var term = document.getElementById('term');
var entity = document.getElementById('entity');
let termAndEntity = [term, entity];

termAndEntity.forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener('keyup', getJson);
});



function getJson() {
    fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term='+term.value.toLowerCase()+'&entity='+entity.value.toLowerCase())
        .then(function (response) {
            
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            
            let result = '';
            try{
                data.results.forEach(function (song) {
                    console.log(song);
                    result += `<li>${song.artistName} - ${song.trackName}</li>`;
                });
            }
            catch{}
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

        })
        .catch(function (empty) {
            console.log(empty);
        });
```

}

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)

Do you know how can i display the message if nothing is found?

Also, i should add some kind of loader when the list is refreshing after each keyup.